# Is RASPA2 a sensible Monte Carlo software to find adsorption sites within porous materials?

Tags: density-functional-theory, monte-carlo

Looking to find sorption sites of species including (H2, CO2, and N2) within porous materials (metal-organic frameworks) for further DFT work. Is RASPA2 a sensible Monte Carlo software to achieve this? Is adsorption sites found by Radial Pair Distribution analysis, if not how?

Comment: The folks who made it know what they are doing and have a good reputation. The code is not known for being user friendly though. The science should be good.

Comment: Welcome to MMSE :)

Comment: @B.Kelly perhaps you can write an answer? It would be nice for this question to exit the unanswered queue (and also you'll get the silver necromancer badge in *addition* to the bronze revival badge, for answering a question that's more than 6 months old!). I'll add a community wiki answer so the unanswered queue can prioritize questions that haven't actually been answered yet, and I can delete the community wiki as soon as you write an answer (if you want to)!

Answer (score 1):

[B. Kelly's comment](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/10662/is-raspa2-a-sensible-monte-carlo-software-to-find-adsorption-sites-within-porous#comment22844_10662) is essentially an answer to the question:

> "The folks who made it know what they are doing and have a good reputation. The code is not known for being user friendly though. The science should be good."

I can delete this Community Wiki answer if B. Kelly or someone else wants to write a better answer! Just write a comment to let me know :)

Comment: At this point, I cannot write a better answer. I have not used it myself as of yet.